# Infinite datatable loading too much data initially

Tags: lightning-datatable

I am trying to build a component that expands the items to approve information.  Sometimes there could be dozens or more of awaiting approvals.  There are no errors but is appears to be loading too much data (all of it) in the init.  How can I fix this?  TIA!

Component

```
<aura:component controller="ItemsToApprove"  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="data" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

<!-- Infinite loading-->
    <aura:attribute name="enableInfiniteLoading" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="initialRows" type="Integer" default="1"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowsToLoad" type="Integer" default="5"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalNumberOfRows" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="loadMoreStatus" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowNumberOffset" type="Integer" default="2"/>
    <aura:attribute name="currentCount" type="Integer" default="6"/>

  <div class="slds-m-around_xxx-small">

<article class="slds-card">
  <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
      <div class="slds-media__body">
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Your Items to Approve">
            <span>Your Items to Approve ({! v.data.length })</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
      <div class="slds-card__body">

                        <lightning:datatable
                                 keyField="id"
                                 data="{! v.data }"
                                 columns="{! v.columns }"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                 loadMoreOffset="{! v.loadMoreOffset }"
                                 enableInfiniteLoading="{!v.enableInfiniteLoading}"
                                 onloadmore="{! c.loadMoreData }"
                                 />
          {! v.loadMoreStatus }

      </div>

</article>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      var action = component.get('c.PendingApprovals');
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

          component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'RecordURL', type: 'url',sortable: true,initialWidth: 100, typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'RecordName',target: '_self'}}},
              {label: 'Submitter', fieldName: 'Submitter', type: 'text',initialWidth: 100, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}},
            {label: 'Date Submitted', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', initialWidth: 100, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}},
            {label: 'Comments', fieldName: 'Comments', type: 'text', initialWidth: 230, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}},
            {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'text',initialWidth: 100, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}},
            {label: 'Record Type', fieldName: 'RecordType', type: 'text',initialWidth: 150, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}},
            {label: 'Other Info', fieldName: 'MiscInfo', type: 'text',initialWidth: 200, cellAttributes: {"class": {"fieldName": "showClass"}}}
        ]);

                // store the account list in records variable
                var records = response.getReturnValue();
                // iterate each records with forEach loop
                records.forEach(function(record){
                 record.showClass = (record.ElapsedHours > 48 ? 'redcolor' : 'blackcolor');


                });
         component.set('v.data', response.getReturnValue());

        }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    loadMoreData: function (cmp, event, helper) {
            //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
            event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", true);
            //Display "Loading" when more data is being loaded
            cmp.set('v.loadMoreStatus', 'Loading');
            helper.fetchData(cmp, cmp.get('v.rowsToLoad'))
                .then($A.getCallback(function (data) {
                    if (cmp.get('v.data').length >= cmp.get('v.totalNumberOfRows')) {
                        cmp.set('v.enableInfiniteLoading', false);
                        cmp.set('v.loadMoreStatus', '');
                    } else {
                        var currentData = cmp.get('v.data');
                        //Appends new data to the end of the table
                        var newData = currentData.concat(data);
                        cmp.set('v.data', newData);
                        cmp.set('v.loadMoreStatus', 'loading');
                    }
                   event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", false);
                }));
        }


})
```

Helper

```
({
    helperMethod : function() {

    },
fetchData: function(component , rows){
        return new Promise($A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {
            var currentDatatemp = component.get('c.PendingApprovals');
            var counts = component.get("v.currentCount");
            currentDatatemp.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                resolve(a.getReturnValue());
                var countstemps = component.get("v.currentCount");
                countstemps = countstemps+component.get("v.initialRows");
                component.set("v.currentCount",countstemps);
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(currentDatatemp);
        }));

    } ,
})
```

Comment: loadMoreOffset should be either not specified, or a value greater than 0?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, just tried removing it from the datatable, no difference.Still not working correctly.